# Redirect Loop on new WP MultiSite install on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, infinite-loop, multisite

Set up WordPress 4.5.2 on Elastic Beanstalk following this guide: 
http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/deploying-wordpress-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk.pdf

All points of the walkthrough were followed exactly- with the following exceptions...

1. The MySQL database was set up directly through RDS using ElastiCache rather than through the Eliastic Beanstalk interface. (No issues on database connectivity)
2. I am using a development domain name rather than the CloudFront domain. (No issues resolving to any page on the site prior to activating multisite)

NOTE: Domain is registered with GoDaddy (updated with custom NS info). Hosted Zone is set up in Amazon Route53. A Record for domain (no www.) is pointed to the CloudFront endpoint. One CNAME record points www. to just domain (no www.).

WordPress Address and Site Address (in WP General Settings) are both pointed to http://mydevsitename.com

The only active Plugins on the site are W3TotalCache (for CDN through CloudFront - Origin Push) and WP SEO by Yoast (Current versions of both). Theme is 2016 - no modifications.

Enable WP multisite was in my wp-config.php file. 
Enabled subfolder multisite network through Tools / Network. 
Grabbed the code to change .htaccess and wp-config.php

Here is the .htaccess code generated...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Made change to .htaccess using the .htaccess editor in the WP SEO by Yoast plugin to avoid having to deploy a new EBS application. Verified changes by downloading the .htaccess from the active EC2 instance.  (Site still accessible from front end after changes made.)

Here are the wp-config changes generated...

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydevsitename.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I downloaded  the web folder from the staging environment (folder /var/app/current/) locally. I added this code to wp-config.php. Zipped it up and deployed it as a new application in Elastic Beanstalk. This creates a redirect loop on the front end of the site.

I am still able to navigate through WP Admin areas without any issues - 100% functionality. (Uploading media, installing plugins, adding new sites to the network, etc.) ZERO functionality on the front end because of the redirect loop.

This makes no sense to me whatsoever. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a resolution to this issue. Thought I would share in case anyone else runs into the same problem...

The issue was caused because of when the WordPress installation was converted to multisite.

Even though this was a fresh install, the WP install should be switched over to multisite BEFORE setting up W3 Total Cache. I'm assuming that the cache files and configurations for a single site can create redirect loops when WP is switched to multisite.